MSbuild missing issue after updating to VSC 1.88 March 2024 update
When I try to Run Build Task.. command, to create an executable file out of my code, I get this error and no .exe file is created. Here the error:
Executing task: msbuild /property:GenerateFullPaths=true /t:build
/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary 

msbuild : The term 'msbuild' is not recognized as the name of a
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
of  the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
correct and try again.         At line:1 char:1
+ msbuild /property:GenerateFullPaths=true /t:build /consoleloggerparam ...
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (msbuild:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 

 *  The terminal process
"C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command
msbuild /property:GenerateFullPaths=true /t:build
/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary" terminated with exit code: 1.

I must add that I tried uninstalling the current version and going back to the previous one (Feb 2024), installing it as Admin as I saw on a previous post, but none of these worked out.
I would like to be able to run my code as .exe files, but I don't get to create them.
I have some MSbuild extensions installed from within VSC, and tried the computer restart after each of these steps.
